# Inject several implementations of an abstraction in a class

Tags: java, spring, spring-framework-beans

I hope you're doing well, I have a doubt when I try to create a method that can validate some business rules.

In this case, I have a class

```
public class ValidationUtils {

    final List<CreditValidations> creditValidations;

    public ValidationUtils(){
        creditValidations = Arrays.asList(
            new ValidateAge(),
            new ValidateSalary()
        );
    }

    public ValidationRs passAllValidations(Client client){
        final var validationsFailed = new ArrayList<String>();
        boolean validationResult = false;
        for (CreditValidations creditValidationClasses : creditValidations){
            validationResult = Boolean.logicalXor(creditValidationClasses .validate(client,validationsFailed),
                validationResult);
        }
        final var rs = new ValidationRs();
        rs.setSuccessfulValidations(validationResult);
        rs.setValidationsFailed(validationsFailed);
        return rs;
    }


}
```

this class has a method called "passAllValidations" That method can evaluate each CreditValidation implementation and join their results, Using this code I don't need to create more methods when I have a new validation, only extends the abstraction and create the new Validation class and inject it in the ValidationUtils constructor.

the abstraction and implementation of CreditValidations look like

```
public abstract class CreditValidations {

    protected final String errorCode;

    protected CreditValidations(final String errorCode) {
        this.errorCode = errorCode;
    }

    protected abstract boolean validate(final Client client,final List<String> validationsFailed);

    protected boolean evaluateValidation(boolean validationResult, List<String> validationsFailed){
        if (!validationResult){
            setCode(validationsFailed);
        }
        return  validationResult;
    }

    protected String getErrorCode() {
        return this.errorCode;
    }

    protected void setCode(List<String> failedValidations) {
        failedValidations.add(errorCode);
    }
}
```

```
public class ValidateAge extends CreditValidations {

    public ValidateAge() {
        super(CreditValidationErrorEnum.ERROR_VALIDATING_AGE.getCode());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean validate(final Client client, List<String> validationsFailed) {
        return this.evaluateValidation(client.getAge() >= 18,validationsFailed);
    }

}
```

in summary, my question is referring to the dependency injection in the class ValidationUtils, I don't know if it way is correct or if Spring Framework has some things that help me to inject all of the CreditValidation implementations and avoid using Array.asList(new NewValidationClass()) or another design pattern which can help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Spring will gather implementations of an interface/extentions of a base class and inject them where a `List` is required. Try it.

Comment: Yes!  Mark all `CreditValidator` implementations as an @Component, and spring will make a `List<CreditValidator>` available for injection (to avoid the `Array.asList(...)` ickyness).